# Safari: problem with object-contain while trying to keep aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, safari, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to make an image inside a slider to keep its aspect ratio. With Chrome, it works like a charm. But unfortunately Safari is driving me crazy and I can't figure out why this is happening.

Screenshot from Chrome:

[image: chrome working screenshot]

and here the screenshot from Safari:
[image: safari not working screenshot]

I have no idea why, but Safari keeps "inserting" these gray spacings around the image.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<div class="slideshow-wrapper">
  <button
    type="button"
    class="visually-hidden slideshow__pause"
    data-id="ee8tnv"
    aria-live="polite"
  >
    <span class="slideshow__pause-stop">
      <svg
        aria-hidden="true"
        focusable="false"
        role="presentation"
        class="m-icon m-icon--pause"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      >
        <path d="M14,19H18V5H14M6,19H10V5H6V19Z"></path>
      </svg>

      <span class="m-icon__fallback-text">Diashow pausieren</span>
    </span>
    <span class="slideshow__pause-play">
      <svg
        aria-hidden="true"
        focusable="false"
        role="presentation"
        class="m-icon m-icon--play"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      >
        <path d="M8,5.14V19.14L19,12.14L8,5.14Z"></path>
      </svg>

      <span class="m-icon__fallback-text">Diashow abspielen</span>
    </span>
  </button>

  <div
    class="
      keep-ar
      slideshow slideshow--small
      box
      slick-initialized slick-slider slick-dotted
    "
    id="Slideshow-ee8tnv"
    data-autoplay="false"
    data-speed="5000"
  >
    <div class="slick-list draggable">
      <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 750px">
        <div
          class="
            slideshow__slide slideshow__slide--image-mgx38u
            slick-slide slick-current slick-active
          "
          data-slick-index="0"
          aria-hidden="false"
          role="tabpanel"
          id="slickSlide00"
          aria-labelledby="slickDot00"
          tabindex="-1"
          style="
            width: 375px;
            position: relative;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            z-index: 999;
            opacity: 1;
          "
        >
          <div class="keep-ar slideshow__image">
            <picture>
              <source
                srcset="
                  //img-2.versacommerce.de/resize=master/gravity=center/++/vc-unsplash-proxy.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/UWkCguB75-E.jpg
                "
              />
              <img
                data-src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
                alt=""
              />
            </picture>
          </div>

          <div class="slideshow__text-wrap slideshow__overlay">
            <div class="keep-ar slideshow__text-content">
              <div class="page-width">
                <h2 class="h1 mega-title slideshow__title">Foto-Slide</h2>

                <span class="mega-subtitle slideshow__subtitle">
                  Erzähle deine Geschichte mit Videos und Fotos
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slideshow__slide slideshow__slide--image-gy5hav slick-slide"
          data-slick-index="1"
          aria-hidden="true"
          role="tabpanel"
          id="slickSlide01"
          aria-labelledby="slickDot01"
          tabindex="-1"
          style="
            width: 375px;
            position: relative;
            left: -375px;
            top: 0px;
            z-index: 998;
            opacity: 0;
          "
        >
          <div class="keep-ar slideshow__image">
            <picture>
              <source
                srcset="
                  //img-3.versacommerce.de/resize=master/gravity=center/++/vc-unsplash-proxy.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/c9FQyqIECds.jpg
                "
              />
              <img
                data-src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
                alt=""
              />
            </picture>
          </div>

          <div class="slideshow__text-wrap slideshow__overlay">
            <div class="keep-ar slideshow__text-content">
              <div class="page-width">
                <h2 class="h1 mega-title slideshow__title">Foto-Slide</h2>

                <span class="mega-subtitle slideshow__subtitle">
                  Erzähle deine Geschichte mit Videos und Fotos
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="slick-dots" style="display: block" role="tablist">
      <li
        class="slick-active"
        aria-hidden="false"
        role="tab"
        aria-selected="true"
        aria-controls="slickSlide00"
        id="slickDot00"
      >
        <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">
          Slide 1
        </button>
      </li>
      <li
        role="tab"
        aria-selected="false"
        aria-controls="slickSlide01"
        id="slickDot01"
      >
        <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">
          Slide 2
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the SCSS:

```
slideshow-height-small: 475px;
$slideshow-height-medium: 650px;
$slideshow-height-large: 775px;

$slideshow-loader: #fff;
$z-index-slideshow-image: 1;
$z-index-slideshow-video: 2;
$z-index-slideshow-text: 3;
$z-index-slideshow-controls: 4;
$color-slideshow-close-bg: #fff;
$color-slideshow-close-text: #000;

.slideshow-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.keep-ar.slideshow {
  height: fit-content; //$slider-small--medium;
  height: -moz-fit-content; //$slider-small--medium;

  &--medium {
    height: fit-content; //$slider-small--medium;
    height: -moz-fit-content; //$slider-medium--medium;
  }

  &--large {
    height: fit-content; //$slider-large--medium;
    height: -moz-fit-content; //$slider-large--medium;
  }

  // Make sure slides fill full height
  .slideshow__slide,
  .slick-list,
  .slick-track {
    height: fit-content; //100%;
    height: -moz-fit-content;
  }

  .slick-prev,
  .slick-next {
    height: fit-content; //100%;
    height: -moz-fit-content;
  }

  .slick-dots {
    bottom: 0.5em; //$gutter-site-mobile;
  }

  @include respond('medium') {
    height: fit-content; //$slider-small--medium;
    height: -moz-fit-content;

    &--medium {
      height: fit-content; //$slider-medium--medium;
      height: -moz-fit-content;
    }

    &--large {
      height: fit-content; //$slider-large--medium;
      height: -moz-fit-content;
    }
  }

  @include respond('large') {
    height: fit-content; //$slider-small--large;
    height: -moz-fit-content;

    &--medium {
      height: fit-content; //$slider-medium--large;
      height: -moz-fit-content;
    }

    &--large {
      height: fit-content; //$slider-large--large;
      height: -moz-fit-content;
    }
  }
}

.slideshow {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: $slider-small--medium;
  margin-bottom: 0;

  &--medium {
    height: $slider-medium--medium;
  }

  &--large {
    height: $slider-large--medium;
  }

  // Make sure slides fill full height
  .slideshow__slide,
  .slick-list,
  .slick-track {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .slick-prev,
  .slick-next {
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 40px;
  }

  .slick-prev {
    left: 0;
  }

  .slick-next {
    right: 0;
  }

  .slick-dots {
    bottom: $gutter-site-mobile;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);

    // sass-lint:disable SelectorDepth
    li button::before {
      color: $color-slideshow-dots;
    }
  }

  @include respond('medium') {
    height: $slider-small--medium;

    &--medium {
      height: $slider-medium--medium;
    }

    &--large {
      height: $slider-large--medium;
    }
  }

  @include respond('large') {
    height: $slider-small--large;

    &--medium {
      height: $slider-medium--large;
    }

    &--large {
      height: $slider-large--large;
    }
  }
}

.video-is-playing .slick-dots {
  // sass-lint:disable no-important
  display: none !important;
}

// Pause button (focusable by keyboard only)
.slideshow__pause:focus {
  clip: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  color: $color-btn-primary-text;
  background-color: $color-btn-primary;
  padding: $gutter-site / 2;
  z-index: $z-index-skip-to-content;
  transition: none;

  .video-is-playing & {
    display: none;
  }
}

.slideshow__pause-stop {
  display: block;

  .is-paused & {
    display: none;
  }
}

.slideshow__pause-play {
  display: none;

  .is-paused & {
    display: block;
  }
}

/*================ General slide styles ================*/
.slideshow__slide {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow__link {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  &:active,
  &:focus {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.slideshow__overlay {
  @include overlay($z-index-slideshow-text);
}

/*================ Slide images ================*/

.keep-ar.slideshow__image {
  img {
    object-fit: contain; //cover;
  }
}

.slideshow__image {
  transition: $transition-image-slideshow;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100%;

  picture {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
  }

  img {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  .slick-initialized &,
  .no-js & {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .slideshow__slide--background-video & {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .no-autoplay & {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

// z-index stacking issues in oldIE
.ie9 {
  .slideshow__slide {
    // sass-lint:disable no-important
    z-index: 1 !important;
  }

  .slick-dots {
    z-index: 2;
  }
}

/*================ Slide text ================*/
.slideshow__text-wrap {
  height: 100%;

  .slideshow__link & {
    cursor: inherit;
  }

  .slideshow__slide--has-background-video & {
    padding-top: $gutter-site * 3;
  }

  .video-is-playing & {
    display: none;
  }

  .slideshow__slide.video-is-paused & {
    display: none;
  }
}

.slideshow__text-content {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  @include transform(translateY(-40%));
  opacity: 0;
  transition: $transition-text-slideshow;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  z-index: $z-index-slideshow-text;

  .slick-active &,
  .no-js & {
    @include transform(translateY(-50%));
    opacity: 1;
  }

  &::after {
    content: '';
    @include spinner(40px, $slideshow-loader);
    @include animation(spin 0.65s infinite linear);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.29, 0.63, 0.44, 1);
    bottom: -$gutter-site;
    left: 50%;
  }

  .slick-initialized &,
  .no-js & {
    &::after {
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      content: none;
    }
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .keep-ar.slideshow__text-content {
        font-size: 70%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    .keep-ar.slideshow__text-content {
        font-size: 60%;
    }
}


.slideshow__title {
  color: $color-overlay-title-text;
}

.slideshow__subtitle {
  display: block;
  color: $color-overlay-title-text;
}
```

Comment: What element is the gray in? (e.g. from inpecting through your browser dev console). Could you put up a working snippet so we can try it ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by just setting the height of the `img` to 100%.

```js
img {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  **height: 100%;**
  object-fit: cover;
}
```